# Use of HBase Get constructor with rowOffset

Tags: hbase, bigdata

What is use of this specific Get constructor in Hbase?

public Get(byte[] row,
           int rowOffset,
           int rowLength)

I am looking for examples to use parts(s) of composite row_key to get columns without doing full table scan. Any pointers appreciated.